# Two HTTP notification methods

Tags: ruby, http

I have two very similar methods, which make HTTP requests, the difference is that one makes PUT and another GET. Is there any proper Ruby way not to repeat the setup code and not to pass the flag parameter?

```
def notify_client(url, params)
  uri = URI.parse(url)
  https = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
  https.use_ssl = !Rails.env.development?
  req = Net::HTTP::Patch.new(uri.path)
  req.body = {data: {attributes: params}}.to_json
  res = https.request(req)
  puts "Response #{res.code} #{res.message}: #{res.body}"
end

def notify_vendor(url, params)
  uri = URI.parse(url)
  https = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
  https.use_ssl = !Rails.env.development?
  req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.path)
  req.body = {data: {attributes: params}}.to_json
  res = https.request(req)
  puts "Response #{res.code} #{res.message}: #{res.body}"
end
```

Comment: Do you mean PUT or PATCH? What flag parameter are you talking about?

Comment: One method makes GET and other PUT request the rest of the code is similar and I wanted to differentiate then somehow

Comment: Then why does your code say `Net::HTTP::Patch`?

Comment: My mistake but that's not relevant to what I was asking

Comment: _Every_ detail is relevant in a code review, because every detail matters when running code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In such cases I try to move repeated code to separate method that accepts block.

```
def notify_client(url, params)
  notify(url, params) { |path| Net::HTTP::Patch.new(path) }
end

def notify_vendor(url, params)
  notify(url, params) { |path| Net::HTTP::Get.new(path) }
end

def notify(url, params)
  uri = URI.parse(url)
  https = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
  https.use_ssl = !Rails.env.development?
  req = yield uri.path
  req.body = {data: {attributes: params}}.to_json
  res = https.request(req)
  puts "Response #{res.code} #{res.message}: #{res.body}"
end
```

That code refactoring quite simple. If you need more details - let me know.

Answer (score 2):

I like Sergii's solution a lot, but just as an extra idea, this is also possible:

```
%w(vendor client).each do |subject|
  define_method("notify_#{subject}") do |url, params|
    uri = URI.parse(url)
    https = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
    https.use_ssl = !Rails.env.development?
    req = (subject == 'client' ? Net::HTTP::Patch.new(uri.path) : Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.path))
    req.body = {data: {attributes: params}}.to_json
    res = https.request(req)
    puts "Response #{res.code} #{res.message}: #{res.body}"
  end
end
```

You create two methods dynamically. Again, not as elegant as Sergii's but this will still work.

Answer (score 1):

One way is a block, already shown, the other sending a string/symbol to select the method:

```
def request(url, params, method)
  uri = URI.parse(url)
  https = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
  https.use_ssl = !Rails.env.development?
  class_obj = Net::HTTP.const_get(method.to_s.capitalize)
  req = class_obj.new(uri.path)
  req.body = {data: {attributes: params}}.to_json
  res = https.request(req)
  puts "Response #{res.code} #{res.message}: #{res.body}"
end
```

In any case, using *net/http* is slightly masochistic, there are more friendly libraries, for example [rest-client](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client):

```
response = RestClient::Request.execute(method: method, url: url, params: params)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could inject the class for constructing the request, but this would break the abstraction, as the caller would have to know that we're using `Net::HTTP`. You could pass the HTTP verb as a symbol instead and look up the corresponding class like this:

```
METHOD_CLASS = {get: Net::HTTP::Get, patch: Net::HTTP::Patch}

def notify(url, params, method)
  uri = URI.parse(url)
  https = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
  https.use_ssl = !Rails.env.development?
  req = METHOD_CLASS.fetch(method).new(uri.path)
  req.body = {data: {attributes: params}}.to_json
  res = https.request(req)
  puts "Response #{res.code} #{res.message}: #{res.body}"
end
```

I'd use a block instead for evaluating the response, printing the response shouldn't be a responsibility of this method. Depending on your use case you might want to yield the response to the block only if the request was successful or if it failed.